# How to create new OBIEE 12c server with backup files?

Tags: oracle12c, obiee

I am looking to create/install Oracle Business Intelligence 12c on new machine with backup files.
What are key steps?

Comment: What do you mean "with backup files"?

Comment: Bar & RPD files

Answer (score 0):

a) the BAR contains the RPD
b) Install a new machine and upload the BAR file. It's one command.

https://datacadamia.com/dat/obiee/admin/12c/bar